# maven does not have spring version 3 or version 4?

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I was trying to run a legacy project using spring version 3 with build.gradle:

```
...
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'war'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}

ext {
    org_springframework_version = '3.2.18.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
...
    implementation 'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:2.4.1'
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-web:${org_springframework_version}"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${org_springframework_version}"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring:${org_springframework_version}"
...
}
...
```

but getting the following error when trying to build:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework:spring:3.2.18.RELEASE.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/.../.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring/3.2.18.RELEASE/spring-3.2.18.RELEASE.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring/3.2.18.RELEASE/spring-3.2.18.RELEASE.pom
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I checked https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring/ and it looks like there is no spring 3 or 4 in the repo.

I cannot use any newer spring version as there are tons of other dependencies and legacy code in the project that should be kept as is.

I am confused as to why is this the case or how to build my project now.
Any help is appreciated.

PS. A little background: I have a legacy project that relies on really old tech (Stripes framework) which is straight up refusing to work with spring 5+. It is running on Java 6 now. I want to upgrade it to java 8. But spring 2.x dependency is not letting me to.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using `mavenCentral()` repository?

Comment: Using `repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}` produces same issue nonetheless. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: The full spring jar hasn't been available for quite some time. So yes there is no and has never been a 3 and 4 release of `spring.jar` nor is there now as it only contains the `pom.xml`. So remove the `spring` dependency and replace with things like `spring-context-support` depending on your needs. Also use `mavenCentral()` instead of a hardcoded URL in your repo.

Comment: As I stated before the full spring jar is not available anymore since Spring 2.5. It isn't anymore and will never be anymore, as stated include the individual modules from Spring you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fullblown `spring.jar` hasn't been available since Spring Framework 3.0.0. Spring 2.5.6 is the last one that has the full Spring jar. Since then only the smaller modules have been available.

The versions for 5.x you see are only some top level `pom.xml` files which, I assume, have been published accidentally (as for 6.x they aren't there anymore).

In short remove the following line from your dependencies

```
implementation "org.springframework:spring:${org_springframework_version}"
```

So it doesn't try to resolve something that hasn't been available since Spring 2.5.6 anymore. What you should include are the dependencies for the modules you need (something like the below dependencies).

```
implementation "org.springframework:spring-web:${org_springframework_version}"
implementation "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${org_springframework_version}"
implementation "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:${org_springframework_version}"
implementation "org.springframework:spring-orm:${org_springframework_version}"
implementation "org.springframework:spring-oxm:${org_springframework_version}"
```

As an additional note replace

```
maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
}
```

with

```
mavenCentral()
```

This will allow Gradle to pick a better suited mirror of Maven for your environment.

Comment: What if I want to use spring 3.x or 4.x?

I have a legacy project that relies on really old tech (Stripes framework) which is straight up refusing to work with spring 5+. It is running on Java 6 now. I want to upgrade it to java 8. But spring 2.x dependency is not letting me to.

Comment: Where do I stsate you cannot use Spring 3 or 4? I state you need to include the indivudual modules and remove the all encompassing dependency as that simply doesn't exists anymore!.

Comment: `include the indivudual modules` - this is actually confusing me as to how to do that. i mean should i download it from somewhere and declare in build.gradle? or do i include dependency in some other means? (for spring 4.x)

Comment: You include it like you already did with `spring-web` or `spring-webmvc`. You have already included those modules in your build.gradle, just add the other modules that you need.

Comment: Okay, if I declare it like `implementation 'org.springframework:spring:4.3.30.RELEASE'`, I get gradle error : `Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework:spring:4.3.30.RELEASE.
     Searched in the following locations:...` ... Am I missing something here? You already said they dont exist anymore...(?) So including them like this shouldn't work, right?

Comment: Third time **remove the all encompassing dependency**... I explicitly state that you need to remove that dependency in my answer and you keep shoving it in there.

Comment: So, use `spring-web, spring-webmvc, spring-jdbc` etc, but not `spring`. Sorry for getting it so slow.

Comment: Exactly... Figure out which modules you need and include those. Included that in the answer.

Comment: hint: the "spring" dependency has been renamed "spring-core" (but may have had smaller bits split off).

Comment: The `spring` dependency hasn't been renamed to `spring-core`. `spring-core` is only a small subset of what was in the `spring` module (which included everything but web related stuff).